# no callbacks work with my new universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, callback, universal

I believe that I did everything necessary to change my app for ipad (was for iphone at start). I can toggle the build status to either iphone (only), ipad (only) or iphone/ipad - and the app launches either in ipad or iphone simulator. I can do that forth and back at will (I am saying this because I had no questions from xcode asking me to "upgrade to ipad" and have no new "mainwindowxib-ipad" like I read somewhere...)

I added the idiom to check for ipad and basically for one of my xib, instead of using the string of my xib to create the controller, I use the one for the ipad. So it is a new xib for ipad with all same graphical objects ( enlarged ;-) ) . I added the callbacks to function correctly with IB.

I can see everything fine and arrive on my new ipad view BUT when I click on a button... nothing happened like if my callbacks don't work. It is very surprising and actually I have no idea where to look as I compared most of the parameters between my iphone and ipad view and they are identical as far as I can see.

It must be something damn obvious so if one of you had the same issue and it was a very simple answer ... I guess that would be what I missed!

Thanks for your help in advance

Cheers,
geebee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was caused because of that : answer in that post:

[2 XIB and 1 viewcontroller but functions don't work in the ipad XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982674/2-xib-and-1-viewcontroller-but-functions-dont-work-in-the-ipad-xib)