# 2 XIB and 1 viewcontroller but functions don't work in the ipad XIB

Tags: iphone, ipad, callback, xib, viewcontroller

I believe that I did everything necessary to change my app for ipad (was for iphone at start). I can toggle the build status to either iphone (only), ipad (only) or iphone/ipad - and the app launches either in ipad or iphone simulator. I can do that forth and back at will.

I added the idiom to check for ipad and basically for one of my xib, instead of using the string of my xib to create the controller, I use the one for the ipad. So it is a new xib for ipad with all same graphical objects ( enlarged ;-) ) . I added the callbacks to function correctly with IB.

I can see everything fine and arrive on my new ipad view BUT when I click on one of my buttons... nothing happened like if my callbacks don't work. It is very surprising and actually I have no idea where to look as I compared most of the parameters between my iphone and ipad view and they are identical as far as I can see.

It must be something damn obvious so if one of you had the same issue and it was a very simple answer ... I guess that would be what I missed!

Thanks for your help in advance

Cheers,
geebee

EDIT1: Some code as requested

at start I have that to decide either way:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
   examTFVC_NIB=@"ExamTFViewController-iPad";
 }
else
{
   examTFVC_NIB=@"ExamTFViewController";
 }
```

Then to go to the right view:

```
    ExamTFViewController *examTFViewController = [[ExamTFViewController alloc]                        
                                                  initWithNibName:globals.examTFVC_NIB bundle:nil];
```

But I have no problem loading the correct XIB. The issue is really the callback functions not being called...

Thanks for the help.

EDIT2:
I also realised that calling the extension of the xib xxx~ipad allows to avoid the example code above. And it works - but still no function can be called.

EDIT3:
**IMPORTANT FINDING**: if I move my buttons higher and on the left of the screen: they work! So it seems that the functions are called if the event are in the region of an iphone screen although I am on an ipad screen. I guess know it would be more obvious to find the issue! thanks for any help – geebee just now

ANSWER

[iPad touch detected only in 320x480 region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653761/ipad-touch-detected-only-in-320x480-region)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

// to correct region size
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[window setFrame:rect]; 

// now, display your app
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

** OR OTHER SOLUTION **

Check the full screen at launch checkbox - only present in the ipad xib MainWindow

Comment: Did you hook up your IBAction methods to the iPad xib file?

Comment: I know that it is the obvious and yes I did hook up the methods. What can it be?

Comment: I added some of the code - hoping it helps - thanks for help in advance

Comment: It almost **has** to be something in the .xib file, I would think.  You've probably already done this a few times but look at ExamTFViewController-iPad.xib (check the name) and verify that the File's Owner shows the right class in the Identity Inspector (and that everything in the Connections Inspector looks good when File's Owner is the selected object).

Comment: If you have IBOutlets defined as well, it would be interesting to know if they're being set up correctly by the time viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: Thanks Phillip for the help. I again check the class in the identity inspector and it is the correct one. The connections are the same than for the iphone version. (in fact everything is the same as far as I can see).

Comment: and on your second comment - I have IBOutlets and I assume that they are correctly assigned as I see correctly the name I set on the view when I launched the app. It makes me think that if I was setting the Connections programmatically instead than in the inspector, things might changed.. how do I do that already?

Comment: IMPORTANT FINDING: if I move my buttons higher and on the left of the screen: they work! So it seems that the functions are called if the event are in the region of an iphone screen although I am on an ipad screen. I guess know it would be more obvious to find the issue! thanks for any help

Comment: solved finally  - Thanks Philip -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally solved - with 2 methods - programmatically or via IB - in the edited section of the post.